# Missing image/icon in GNOME's desktop notification

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gnome, notify

I'm trying to display a simple GNOME desktop notification through a Python script. According to [GNOME's specification](https://developer.gnome.org/notification-spec/#icons-and-images) it's possible to display an image with the notification through a simple file URI *(file://)*, but it just refuses to show it in my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from gi.repository import Notify
icon = "file://~/icon.png"
Notify.init("Hello world")
Hello = Notify.Notification.new("Hello world", "This is an example notification", icon)
Hello.show()
```

A blank area is displayed where the icon should've been. I've also tried with an *.ico* format, to no avail.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Try replacing `~` in the string icon with the full name of your home directory?

Comment: It works, I'm so embarrassed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `~` in the string `icon` with the full name of your home directory. Notify has trouble expanding that path by itself, so make it explicit to remove the problem.